# remove specific content from showing up on google search

Tags: google-search

m working on website.the client is demanded to hide specific content of webpage from google search.
can I block any word or paragraph not file from google search
I have no idea about it. pls help me.

Comment: Does the client want to stop Google indexing the site you are building?

Comment: no he only want to stop searching any word or paragarph of web page

Answer (score 1):

You use a file called robots.txt describing what web robots such as Google search are allowed and not allowed to fetch.

See http://www.robotstxt.org/

Comment: it hides only file not content lyk any word "person"

Comment: Use client rendered scripts (javascript) to render the word on the user browser. Make sure the javascript wont contain the word you are trying to hide, so you'll need to be clever.